# Updating variables with Discord.JS

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to work out how to update variables that are declared at runtime.

In my code it's a simple random number generator. It works but doesn't update, i.e. if the slash command /rng is used, alpha never updates past the initial number it picked, so it just repeats the same number at each use of /rng and I understand why. At the initial run, alpha is updated to a random number but it's never updated again unless the script is ran again which isn't possible in it's current configuration unless I restart the bot.

I'm not even looking for someone to fix the code, more so a concept I can go look up or read into so I can learn.

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('discord.js');

const alpha = Math.floor(Math.random() * 11);
console.log(alpha);

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('rng')
        .setDescription('Number between 1 & 10'),
    async execute(interaction) {
        await interaction.reply(`${alpha}`);
    },
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everytime you run the script with slash command, it is running the code inside `module.exports`. In other words, variable outside `module.exports` are constants, which will be only declared once when the bot started up.

To get a different variable each of the time using the command, simply put `const alpha ...` inside `module.exports`, within the `execute` function.

```js
module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('rng')
        .setDescription('Number between 1 & 10'),
    async execute(interaction) {
        const alpha = Math.floor(Math.random() * 11);
        console.log(alpha);
        await interaction.reply(`${alpha}`);
    },
};
```

Comment: I had actually tried this and it errored out the first time, re-looking at it, I now realise I had missed const before alpha. It works now, thanks to you :)